# How to handle detached elements when using Cypress for exploratory testing?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, integration-testing, cypress

I have made a Cypress script for testing a large site "exploratory", meaning it will parse all the links and elements and interact with them all, in the hunt for unexpected JavaScript- or server-exceptions (side-note: i can't find examples of this online?). It traverses through the entire site clicking like crazy, which works quite well. However from time to time the tests stops on the dreaded "CypressError: cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM."

```
Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them.

The previous command that ran was:

  cy.wrap()

This DOM element likely became detached somewhere between the previous and current command.
```

I understand this happens as the script is interacting with the page animating and toggling state, and it is ok for the script to skip all these detached elements and continue its run, however i can't manage to work how to ignore the error. You would think it is enough to check the Cypress-dom-helpers, but they don't seem to do the job (see below). I have tried using greater values for cy.wait() but for some reason it still doesn't catch detached elements even though all page manipulation from the last interaction has finished.

Note that the `wrap` works, but not the click.

```
        if (Cypress.dom.isVisible(element[0]) && !Cypress.dom.isDetached(element[0])) {
            cy.wrap(element[0])
                // .scrollIntoView()
                .click({ force: true })
                .then(() => cy.wait(100));
        }
```

I don't want to swallow all unexpected errors, as they might be meaningful... Running out of ideas here.

---

***EDIT***

Here is more of my code leading up to cy.wrap(). As you see, it is quite rudimentary to just catch obvious javascript and server-errors:

```
clickAllElements = () => {
    this.getAllClickableElements().each(this.clickElement); //running it twice to toggle state
    this.getAllClickableElements().each(this.clickElement);
};

getClickableElementsSelector = () => "button:visible, a:visible[href='javascript:;'], a:visible[href='#'], a:visible[href='javascript:void(null)'], a:not([href])";
getAllClickableElements = () => cy.get(this.getClickableElementsSelector()).not(".disabled");

clickElement = (element) => {
    if (Cypress.dom.isVisible(element[0]) && !Cypress.dom.isDetached(element[0])) {
        this.checkMainError();

        cy.wrap(element[0]) // i tried cy.get here as well to re-get the element, but with the same detached error on click
            // .scrollIntoView() //ideally i'd like to have scrollIntoView here as well, but that won't work with hidden elements (as click({force}) does)
            .click({ force: true })
            .then(() => cy.wait(100));
    }
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the runner, trying out cy.get instead of cy.wrap. The result is identical for cy.wrap: [image: Cypress-runner]

Comment: Cypress usually waits for animations to complete, but this problem is likely caused because you are using `cy.wrap()` which will not wait for anything. What precedes this code snippet? You should probably simplify and chain the click from the previous command.

Comment: Aside from that [Cypress-wait-until](https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-wait-until) could be used to perform the dom tests until the element becomes attached, but that feels like just patching a code smell.

Comment: Thanks @MarionMorrison ! Added more of preceding code to the question.